# AndriodStudios RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

Can someone help me with this code? I am trying to create a recyclerview Adapter however in the override fun onBindViewHolder my textView and imageView has an error saying unresolved reference. However I stated them in the ViewHolder class.

---

```
class CNNRecyclerViewAdapter(data: List<VideoData>, val listener: RecyclerViewClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {
 var videos = data
 set(value) {
 field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
 interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
 fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int)
    }

class ViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
 val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
 val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
    }

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
 R.layout.cnn_list_item, parent, false)
 return ViewHolder(view)
    }

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
 return videos.size
 }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textView.text = videos[position].title
 holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(videos[position].cover)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
 listener.onItemClick(it, position)
 }
 }
}
```

I have the vals in the viewholder but it keeps having resolved reference

Answer (score 0):

Your viewholder `ViewHolder(val view: View)` extends from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)`

```
class ViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

You should change your function *onBindViewHolder*

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)
```

to the following:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
```

since it is in *ViewHolder* that your variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

I really dont know why yours it not working while mine is fine.

```
class CNNRecyclerViewAdapter(
    var data: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val listener: RecyclerViewClickListener? = null
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CNNRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(str: String)
}

inner class ViewHolder(rootView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(rootView) {
    val textView = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

    fun bindData(str: String) {
        textView.text = str
        textView.setOnClickListener {
            listener?.onItemClick(str)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_item_item, parent, false)
    )
}

override fun getItemCount() = data.count()

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindData(data[position])
}
```

}